# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'empty:'

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

```
requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: ".",
                name: "main",
                out: "main-built.js",
                paths: {
                    requireLib: "lib/require",
                    "buildinfo": "empty:",
                    "servlets/rpc/clientInit": "empty:",
                },
                mainConfigFile: "main.js",
                excludeShallow: ["servlets/rpc/clientInit", "buildinfo"],
                findNestedDependencies: true
            },
            optimize: "uglify2"
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why? The buildinfo is loaded as a text module at runtime, no need to add it at build time.

I'm using grunt 0.4.4 with:
[image]

My error message is:

```
>> Error: Error: Loader plugin did not call the load callback in the build:
>> text:
>>   text!buildinfo: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'empty:'
>> Module loading did not complete for: main, sys/pageLife, sys/sammy.routing,   modules/settings/about
>>     at Function.build.checkForErrors (/m/git/cp2/src/main/webapp/js/node_modules/grunt-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27238:19)
```

Comment: As I recall `r.js` provides some context with the error message. While someone might guess what the problem is, it would help us help you if we had the context for the error message.

Comment: Well the error message is essentially (the title) all the context.

Comment: Ok, here's a hunch. Try putting `"text!buildinfo": "empty:"` in the `paths` config in your gruntfile.

Comment: That was my first thought too... but no it's not working.

Comment: It seems there is no real solution for this (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/requirejs/EnSH_-rGsVI) other than filling a feature request for the RequireJS team.

Comment: Actually, with what I see there having an `excludeShallow` that specifies `"text!buildinfo"` should do it. (And I believe you can drop `buildinfo` from the `paths`.) James mentions that the issue the other person is having is probably due to the absolute path.